# El la tabla me muestra el dato como [object object]

Tags: html, html5, angular, typescript, aplicación-web

Al momento de codificar que el rol que selecciono en el formulario se muestre en la tabla me sale que es un [object object], la tengo definida en los dos lados, pero no muestra el valor con el que se guardo cuando cree el usuario.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la parte de codigo del html lo tengo especificado que se muestre

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="role">
     <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> role</th>
     <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{ element.role}} </td>
</ng-container>
```

y en el TS lo tengo de la suguiente manera

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RestService } from '../../rest.service';
import { CommonService } from '../../common.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-list',
  templateUrl: './user-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-list.component.css']
})
export class UserListComponent implements OnInit {
  public dataSource: any=[];
  public displayedColumns: string [] = ['id', 'emailAddress', 'fullName', 'role']
  public userList: any;

  constructor(private rest: RestService, private common: CommonService) {
    this.loadData()
    
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.common.addProject.subscribe(result=>{
      this.loadData()
      
    })
  }
  loadData(){
    this.rest.get("http://localhost:1337/user?sort=id DESC")
    .subscribe(data =>{
      this.dataSource=data
    })
  }
  selectUser(id:number){
    this.common.loadProjectData(id)
  }

}
```

Comment: Eso es porque "role" no es un string, es un objeto. Debes mirar qué campos tiene y que imprima lo que necesitas... por ejemplo `{{ element.role.name }}`

Comment: me funciono cuando lo agrege, pero me me borra el ultimo usuario de la tabla

Comment: y en la parte del formulario no me muestra los datos

Comment: Primero, yo no sé qué campos hay en tu objeto `role`, solo te puse un ejemplo... es cosa tuya mirarlo. Y si tienes más dudas lo correcto sería que abras una pregunta nueva... si lo que quieres es añadir más información a esta, utiliza el botón [edit] y modifica tu pregunta añadiendo lo que consideres necesario. Eso si, por favor sé más concreta, "no me muestra los datos" da 0 información al respeto. Aparece algo en consola? da algún error? Qué significa "Funcionó cuando lo agregué pero ahora me borra el último usuario de la tabla"? No veo que borres nada con ese HTML... añade pruebas,por favor